# how can i get a jPanel that is inside a JtabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I'm developing  a Image Editor in java, i inserted  a  JPanel inside a JTabbedPane, to create a JTabbedPane with tabs that rapresent the Image Filter i want to apply to the image,
i don't know how to obtain a The inner JPanel of  a TabbedPane  to decide witch filter is selected,
because when i do " jTabbedPane1.getSelectedComponent(); " i can obtain only a component not a JComponent..

anyone knows something, sorry for my english thank's a lot..

This is a part of my code:

```
package javaapplication22;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author iDoc
 */
public abstract class FilterTab extends JPanel {

    public FilterTab() {

    }

    protected void ApplyFilter() {

    }

    protected void ResetFilter() {

    }

}
```

---

```
public class InvertFilterTab extends FilterTab {

    private InvertFilter filter;

    public InvertFilterTab ()
    {
        filter = new InvertFilter();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param originalImage
     * @param modifiedImage
     */
    public void ApplyFilter(BufferedImage originalImage, BufferedImage modifiedImage) {
        modifiedImage = filter.filter(originalImage, modifiedImage);
    }

    @Override
    public void ResetFilter() {

    }

}
```

---

```
private void button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    BufferedImage originalImage = jOriginalPanel.getImage();
  //  BufferedImage modifiedImage = new BufferedImage(
    //        originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), 
      //      BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    //modifiedImage = 

    FilterTab ft = jTabbedPane1.getSelectedComponent();   <--- the problem is here

            filter.filter(originalImage, modifiedImage);

    jModifiedPanel.changeImage(modifiedImage);
    jModifiedPanel.repaint();
```

Comment: If you know that you've only added JPanels to your JTabbedPane, you can cast the component to a JPanel. Like: JPanel selected = (JPanel)jTabbedPane1.getSelectedComponent();

Comment: The easiest way is to keep fields holding instances of your components at the class level, so you can get them when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply cast the result ...

```
FilterTab tab = (FilterTab)jTabbedPane1.getSelectedComponent();
```

Remember, `JPanel` extends from `JComponent`, which extends from `Container`, which extends from `Component`

Comment: OK first of all thanks for reply, 
with casting i don't have the message :
incompatible types: Component cannot be converted to FIlterTab

but with the next call to filter.filter(originalImage, modifiedImage);
i obtain the error:

cannot find variable: filter
have you got some ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ft.filter(...)`

Comment: i'm seeing now the the cast don't work, i get this:


Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JPanel cannot be cast to javaapplication22.FilterTab
 at javaapplication22.GUI.button1ActionPerformed(GUI.java:350)
 at javaapplication22.GUI.access$000(GUI.java:23)

Comment: Then what ever you added as the tab component wasn't a FilterTab, without more context, you'll going to have to go back through your code and find what your actually adding to the JTabbedPane